# How to center multi-line text against variable width image

Tags: php, html, css, center

Sorry but this is probably a bit of a 'nuby' type question,

I want to have  a Header and some paragraph text centred along side a variable width picture. To add to the fun , the text must be able to position either left or right of the image, but in the HTML it will always be first. ( this is so that I can stack them on a mobile display using a media query )

I've tried various things including use display:table but it seems to stop working if I float the image.

I could use PHP in Wordpress to set the width of the text div to ('page width' - 'the image width') but there must surely be a better way ?

```
    <!-- text left-->
    <div class="l">
        <div class="td">
            <h2>History</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, excepturi, tenetur deleniti nemo animi repudiandae. Soluta, quia quod magnam nobis!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img src="images/History.jpg"  alt="Our History"><!-- class="img-responsive" -->
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <!-- text right-->
    <div class="r">
        <div class="td">
            <h2>History</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, excepturi, tenetur deleniti nemo animi repudiandae. Soluta, quia quod magnam nobis! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque, officiis deserunt dolor dolorem voluptas distinctio nostrum nihil natus consequatur sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique sunt doloremque fugit quidem aliquam iure dolor maiores voluptate? Similique, nesciunt, ex, unde, quos porro cum quasi facere dolorem eaque incidunt praesentium totam beatae voluptas velit voluptatum maxime officiis suscipit quis iste quisquam molestiae cumque error laudantium corporis vel et sapiente expedita adipisci accusantium doloribus. Fuga quisquam dolore officiis ipsa reprehenderit quae sapiente reiciendis! Ea, recusandae, ab, accusantium, natus eligendi officia laboriosam quo sed odit dolorem asperiores in libero placeat vitae quae. Itaque, iusto quo harum deserunt quidem laboriosam commodi dicta natus voluptate asperiores debitis tempora distinctio officia odio consectetur vero.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <img src="images/History.jpg"  alt="Our History">
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
* {
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.l,.r {
/*  display: table;  */
    width:100%;
/* height: 421px; */
}

.l .td {
    width:38%;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
/*  height: 421px; */
    margin-top:-100px;
/*  float:left; */
/*
    display: table-cell;
        display:table-cell!important;
    vertical-align:middle;
*/
/*  float:none; */
}

.l img {
    float:right;
    width:62%;
}

.r,.l {
    position:relative;
}

.r .td {
    width:38%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    height:60%;
    margin-top:-100px;
    right:0;
}

.r img {
    width:62%;
}

.l .td,.r .td {
    padding-left:5%;
    padding-right:5%;
    max-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: http://tekhunger.com/test/prob1.html

Answer (score 0):

hope this help

add some css,

```
.test1 txtWhiteBg col-xs-12 {
    margin-top:-200px; //adjust to your image size
  }

<div class="row ">
   <div class="test2 noLRPadding col-xs-12">
      <img src="images/History.jpg"  alt="Our History"><!-- class="img-responsive" -->
   </div>
   <div class="test1 txtWhiteBg col-xs-12">
      <h2>History</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a!</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question, Someone suggested I should use a flexbox but they removed their answer for some reason . cheers